# Vacuum-packed unfrozen Polish sausage left out overnight. Safe to eat or not?

Tags: food-safety, pork, sausages, spoilage

I left a new, vacuum-packed Polish sausage (kiełbasa) out accidently overnight.

Should I toss it or cook it and eat it?

Comment: What does the pack say about storage temperature? If it mentions refrigeration, toss it. Cooking does not make unsafe foods safe.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of the other one, because of the specificity.  I'd say the rule is, to be safe, throw it away, but consider - if it's fully cooked, vacuum sealed and unopened, and loaded with salt and preservatives (as store bought polish sausage often is), you're probably okay.  If it's "fresh"/uncooked, no way.